# set repeating alarms within a range and restart the alarms without user interference

Tags: java, android, calendar, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am creating a drinking water reminder application (I've already searched and tried, but I do not see a solution), the idea is for the user to enter a start time, an interval and an end time. Almost everything works fine, but when the end time is reached, the alarm is not set for the next day and it starts sounding every minute or so.

Basically what I want to achieve is that if the end time of the alarm arrived, it will be established for the next day without the intervention of the user.

I've already tried with the methods `Calendar.before ()` and `Calendar.after ()` but I do not see the results.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

// cancel already scheduled reminders
cancelWaterReminder(context);

Calendar calendarEndTime = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarEndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, userPrefs.getWaterReminder_toHour());
calendarEndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, userPrefs.getWaterReminder_toMin());
calendarEndTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Calendar calendarStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendarStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
calendarStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// Enable a Broadcast receiver
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, WaterAlarmReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, WaterAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, DAILY_WATER_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

//Here is where i try to set and reset alarms 
//according to the current hour, start hour and end hour.

if (now.after(calendarEndTime)) 
{
    //calendarStartTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * interval, pendingIntent);
}
else if (calendarStartTime.before(calendarEndTime)) 
{
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * interval, pendingIntent);
    setWaterReminderEndTime(context, userPrefs.getWaterReminder_toHour(), userPrefs.getWaterReminder_toMin());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the problem is in below line:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * interval, pendingIntent);
```

Probably you are setting `interval` as `1` and you have not added the day multiplier (`24`) to schedule for the next day and that's why alarm goes off every minute.

If above is the problem, following change should solve it,

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 24 * interval, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: that's not the problem, the _interval_ is passed as a parameter to my method. The interval has values of 15, 30, 45, 60.

Comment: Oh alright! Are you cancelling your previous alarm after it is set again? Can you also post rest of your code.